# compare base current of different transistors

Tags: bjt

Can you please compare the base current of 2 transistors:

T1 has Vbe = 0.7 V and Vce= 0.7 V
T2 has Vbe = 0.7 V and Vce= 0.1 V

i believe that T1 is in active mode while T2 is in Saturation mode, so the only comparison i am noticing is that Ib(T2) > Ib(T1), if you have any other comments please tell me.

thanks in advance

Comment: I, personally, miss pictures here. You'd save me from drawing it on a piece of paper, if you were to provide some picture.

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing the type of transistor (its parameters) and the emitter or collector current

Comment: What does the C tag have to do with transistors?

Comment: Because all transistor nodes are on a defined potential (voltage) - and assuming the same transistor in both cases - we can, of course, give a qualitative answer. We are not able to give a value for the base currents but we can say if Ib(T1) is smaller or larger than Ib(T2). See my detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

1.) The collector-base voltage for T1 is Vcb=0V. Hence, you are just at the threshold for the active mode.

2.) In case of T2 the base-collector diode also is open allowing an additional current through the base node. The transistor cannot work as an amplifier and Ib(T2)>Ib(T1).

**EDIT 1** : For clarification of some misunderstandings: The OP did ask for the base current Ib - that is the current through the base node, which **NOT** necessarily is identical with the current through the base-emitter path. In case the base-collector junction is forward biased (as in cas 2 with Vce=0.1 V) the base current Ib has two components: Ibe and Ibc.

**EDIT 2** : This effect (current from base to collector) can be clearly verified for Vce=0. For this case, all detailed Ic=f(Vce) graphs show that for Vce=0 all curves start at NEGATIVE Ic values (they do not start at the origin). And negative Ic values describe a current out of the collector node (npn case). This is nothing else than Ibc as part of the current Ib=Ibe+Ibc.

Comment: mkeith - perhaps you can reconsider the downgrading of my answer? I didn`t mention "saturation" - I rather spoke about "amplifier" application. Do you really deny that there is a current from the base to the collector (npn case) if the base-collector diode is open (Vbc=+0.6 volts for the given values)? A simple simulation can proove that the current into the base does increase correspondingly. I repeat: Of course Ib(T2)>Ib(T1).

Comment: Thanks you soooo much LvW and mkeith, i appreciate your contribution to my question